# Difference between react habitat and react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just wanted to know the difference between react router and react habitat. From what I have been reading (which is not much) these two solve the same problem of externalizing components of a website. I would like to know why one would consider one above the other if they are even comparable in this manner.

Comment: `Declarative routing for React.` vs. `A React DOM Bootstrapper designed to harmonise a hybrid 'CMS + React' application.` don't see how to compare each other.

Comment: thank you Gabriel I had not read too much about it and is indeed very different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**React Habitat** does not worry about routes or the application information architecture (IA). It simply lets some other system render HTML pages how ever it likes and will hook up one/or many React apps on the fly when ever it see's targets in the html. If a CMS content author changes the URL of a page, or adds a new page no problem React Habitat doesn't care and will continue to hook up React apps.

**React Router** use routes (urls) to mount React components, this means it needs to know allot about the IA of the application and cant simply be 'dumb' to it like React Habitat. If a CMS content author changes a URL React Router will no longer render, it will require a developer to update the route in the javascript. You could be fancy and dynamically load routes from the CMS but I would question is this too tightly coupled.

They both solve different problems.

1) If you are building a SPA or PWA and want to hold all the IA in the javascript application then use React Router.

2) If a system (.net/php/java/etc) is rendering your HTML such as a CMS and it holds all the IA then use React Habitat.

Comment: thanks, jennas. Since am trying to make a CMS then React Habitat is the better choice. This question was in the early stages when I did not have enough information. I looked into the source code of the framework and have a basic idea of what is going on. Could I setup a skype meeting with you or a mail you for other inquiries regarding habitat?